# Nginx image_filter does not resize after proxy_pass to remote image

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to resize remote image on the fly

```
location ~^/photo/thumb/   {
    rewrite ^/photo/thumb/(\d+)x(\d+)/(.+)$ /photo/original/$3 break;

    proxy_pass  http://remote.url:80;
    proxy_set_header Host      $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_buffer_size 512k;
    proxy_buffers 16 512k;

    image_filter resize $1 $2;
}
```

but the image returned is unchanged. I've tried to hardcode dimensions but image remained unchanged. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have any value for `$1` and `$2` at that point?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, nevertheless I had hardcoded ```image_filter resize 100 100;``` but the image remained unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

I made it work - `rewrite` was the biggest problem and you need to `proxy_pass` to exact URL. I.e. this works for me:

```
location ~^/photo/thumb/(\d+)x(\d+)/(.+)$   {
    proxy_pass  http://remote.url:80/photo/original/$3;
    proxy_set_header Host      $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_buffer_size 512k;
    proxy_buffers 16 512k;

    image_filter resize $1 $2;
}
```